# Extjs Grid, how do make last row unsortable?

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid

Taking a look at the example at: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/locking-grid.html

The last row at the bottom is "wal-mart". How would I make that bottom row unsortable?

The way it is now, if I sort any column, Wal-mart may potentially move with the sort, and no longer be at the bottom. I want it to stay at the bottom, because I'm going to turn the bottom row into a "totals" row that will add up the values of all the rows above it, so it needs to stay at the bottom.

Comment: Ext already has a way for achieving this without sending the total row from the server ... there are examples on the docs

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of the row is to provide summary then you can use grid [Summary feature](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Summary) and then you don't need to solve the problem of sorting.

Comment: Problem is, the rows above are not numbers, they are text and possibly other funky stuff. So I can't just do a simple addition or average calculation to sum the rows. I do the summery manually, but I need my last row to not sort...